# Exporting with Bodymovin does not work as expected

Tags: react-native, after-effects, lottie, bodymovin

I am a newbie to After Effect CC 2018, I have composition which consists of 3 animated video and 1 texture. Then, I export it as JSON using bodymovin extension. Then, I upload the json to lottiefiles.com for Preview, but only the texture display, video animated does not. could anyone please advise me?

Comment: This does not seem to be about programming, which is what Stack Overflow is for. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I am not familiar with After Effects, but you may want to check [other StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name), one of the sister sites might be able to help you, like maybe [Video Processing StackExchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: unfortunately lottie doesn't support video layers.   Here is a link with supported features.
https://airbnb.io/lottie/supported-features.html